# Drag image from computer to div?

Tags: javascript

```
window.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){e.preventDefault();},false);
window.addEventListener("drop",function(e){e.preventDefault();},false);

$('#cover-drop-zone').ondrop = function(e) {
    alert('drop');
    return false;
};
```

I have the above JS.

Here's my HTML.

```
<div id="cover-drop-zone" class="image-drop-zone"><i class="icon-plus"></i></div>
```

When I drag an image from my computer over to the browser window, and over #cover-drop-zone nothing happens.

If I change the target of ondrop to window, it works.

But I do not want the user to be able to drag the image to anywhere in the window.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Some cross-browser method exists:

```
<div class="drop_panel"> 
  drop here 
  <input class="hidden_input" type="file" >
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.drop_panel {
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.hidden_input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

if file dropped fires .hidden_input onChange event

Comment: Your answer does not relate to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536929(v=vs.85).aspx

> You must cancel the default action for `ondragenter` and `ondragover`
>   in order for `ondrop` to fire. In the case of a div, the default
>   action is not to drop. This can be contrasted with the case of an
>   input type=text element, where the default action is to drop. In order
>   to allow a drag-and-drop action on a div, you must cancel the default
>   action by specifying `window.event.returnValue=false` in both the
>   `ondragenter` and `ondragover` event handlers. Only then will `ondrop` fire.

But, I found out that you have to just cancel `ondragover` instead of both.

See the fiddle: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/4B8tE/3/</kbd>